Ubuntu 24.04 netplan cannot enable accept-ra
I try to enable IPv6 SLAAC on Ubuntu 24.04 by configuring /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml as follows:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.xx.xx.xx/24]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.xx.xx.xx
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.xx.xx.xx, 10.xx.xx.xx]
      accept-ra: yes

However, when I run sysctl -a|grep 'accept_ra =', I still find that eno1 does not accept RA:
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eno1.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.eno2.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enxbe3af2b6059f.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 1

and ip addr show with no ipv6 address.
Oddly enough, after running ip -6 route show, executing ip addr show suddenly assigns an IPv6 address and everything related to IPv6 starts working properly. However, the net.ipv6.conf.eno1.accept_ra remains at 0.

I don't know what's going on here, but net.ipv6.conf..accept_ra is 0 on my systems where everything is working.  I assume this is networkd telling the kernel not to handle the RAs because it is going to do that.  So whatever the problem is, the sysctl isn't it.  Are you sure your router is sending RAs?
